Como posso adicionar uma mensagem de erro personalizada no rails?
Gostaria de tipo, por exemplo, criar uma mensagem de erro para quando o usuário tentar acessar um diretório inexistente, como por exemplo um "/sjdsafjkhnfsajhnfjksafsk", ou algo do tipo.

Bom, caso alguém esteja procurando a resposta:
No seu aplicativo rails, existe uma pasta com o nome "public", ela se localiza na raiz de seu projeto. Dentro da tal pasta, há alguns arquivos, como mensagens de erro, etc. Basta modifica-los.
